# How to use ExpressJs + MySQL in correct fashion

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

**PS: Question might seem long, but there are small focused question below.**

So I am among the unfortunate few who have to use MySQL with express just because it made sense. This is to be used as an API backend. I generated an express app using the generator present on their site (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) and installed mysql from mysqljs (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

Now all the examples for express have MongoDb as example and they just use a wrapper. And mysqljs examples don't tell you much either. So here is my project structure with a few particular questions.

```
bin - auto generated files to start the app
config
models (Maybe have a base model which can talk to db wrapper and other models can extend that)
routes
.... index.js
.... users.js etc etc (each included in the app.js to have some sort of structure)
utils
.... db.js (check code below)
app.js
package.json
```

Now this is what I have in my db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'notsoblank',
    database: 'somedevdb'
});

module.exports = pool;
```

And in my route files (like users.js, index.js), I am using this as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../utils/db');
/* GET groups listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var sql = 'SELECT * from groups';
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(rows);
        });
        connection.release();
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then in app.js, this above file will be included like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var groups = require('./routes/groups');

app.use('/apis/groups', groups);

module.exports = app;
```

Now if I am running this app, I will have an API endpoint like `localhost:5000\apis\groups` and this can be consumed by other apps.

Here are my questions based on this:

1. I am importing that db.js in every route file (index.js, users.js, groups.js). Does this mean that there is a db pool created every time we hit an api?
2. I am going to write a lot of plain sql for my work. Now I know that there are a lot of adapters or OEMs, but I just want to write a simple wrapper with methods like getOne or add or delete etc. What will be the best approach for that.
3. Connection.query returns a promise. If I want to do some further manipulations, what's the best way to do this.

Apart from keeping the db credentials in db.js, anything else wrong with this approach that would potentially stop it from scaling?

Comment: You'd be unfortunate if no one else was using it and/or if it was a crappy solution. This is not the case. I suggest walking through one of the many tutorials, such as https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: This is just the basic example of how to include it and get started. No one tells what to do after you are started. I can already create a connection pool and make queries, but I see a lot of code duplication, and overall it looks messy. and sometimes I don't have any idea what is happening with require and use etc.

Comment: Using sequelize or another ORM may help with your code maintenance long term.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know about the ORM available, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: @Amnon
your solution is very basic. 
I think the question posted here is more elaborated than your answer.

Comment: @RajRj you are right - I don't remember the question being so specific - if it hasn't been edited since I answered then I admit my answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to do some kind of db helper module that helps reduce code bloat (though again, I feel like this is a solved problem via the ORMs), that's pretty trivial to do. Just expose whatever functions you want and hide the repetitive stuff.  Something like this would work:

// db.js rather than just exposing the pool

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

// expose the options so that the calling code can inject the password and so on, probably from config or process.env variables.
function db(options){
  // todo: sanitize options and set defaults
  var pool = mysql.createPool(options);

  return {
     query : function(sql, callback){
       db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
            callback(err, rows, fields);
            connection.release();
        });
       });
     }

  }

}


module.exports = db;
```

Calling code would then do something like:

```
var db = require('./db')(myOptions);

db.query('select * from groups', console.log);
```

A couple things wrong with your original code, by the way.

1) You were calling connection.release() in the callback for getting the connection, not returning the query. On slow DB queries that might result in releasing the connection before you finished using it.

2) Unless you're using Promises, you shouldn't "throw" an error in a callback, you have to handle it in some fashion or pass it to the next callback (if their is one).

Comment: so if I require this file in, say all of my routes, will there be separate pools created for each of them? Which will kind of hard to handle because if my db can handle 10 connections at a time, I would like to keep the total number of connections to max 10. If each route creates 10 of its own connection, even lazily, it will be simply wrong.

Comment: Am I on the right track if I think that I need to create just one instance of this db and then every route should use this?

Comment: The way I wrote it, yes, it will create a pool each time you call the exported function. You can use singleton mechanics instead of you want, or else get the options from config in the body of db.js and instantiatebthe pool outside the function, whichever fits best with how you like to work.

Comment: You could also just call the function once and reuse it for all your routes, it just depends on how you're organizing your code.